# JPA: accented character is saved as ? in database

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, internationalization

Our application is running on weblogic 10g and persists data into oracle 9 database via JPA backed by default eclipselink implementation.

Entity is simple:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PLUGINDATA")
@SequenceGenerator(name="plugin_seq", sequenceName="PLUGINDATASEQ", initialValue = 1000, allocationSize = 50)
public class PluginData implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "data", length = 4000, nullable = false)
    private String data;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "XYZ")
protected javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;

entityManager.persist(entity);
```

When I pass string containing accented characters, they are OK in EJB:

```
83, 116, -59, -103, 101, 100, 111, -60, -115, 101, 115, 107, -61, -67, 32, 107, 114, 97, 106
```

but they are stored corrupted in database:

```
83, 116, 63, 63, 101, 100, 111, -60, 63, 101, 115, 107, 63, 63, 32, 107, 114, 97, 106
```

e.g. accented characters are replaced by question mark: `St??edo�?esk?? kraj`

I do not understand it, the code is OK and datasource setting is same like for other applications that work correctly. Any idea?

Edit 1:

This is SID NLS setting (very same like another application database)

```
select DECODE(parameter, 'NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'CHARACTER SET', 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY', 'TERRITORY') name, value 
from v$nls_parameters
where parameter in ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY');

LANGUAGE    ENGLISH
TERRITORY   CZECH REPUBLIC
CHARACTER SET   EE8ISO8859P2
```

Edit 2:

WebLogic / Data source

Connection pool tab has following attributes:

```
URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:SID 
Driver: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
```

Oracle tab: everything is unchecked

Comment: How are you setting the value of `data` before you store it? What is your table/db collation set to? Do you have the ability to set the character encoding in the connection properties? If so, what is it set to?

Comment: Data is set via setter, its content is valid just before persist. I do not manipulate connection in any way. I just let application server to set EntityManager.

Comment: Does it work if you set the character set to WE8ISO8859P1 (that's ISO-8859-1)? The characters in your data that didn't encode properly actually aren't in EE8ISO8859P2 (ISO-8859-2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it works finally. You all were right, that it is the locale problem. Nonetheless it was weblogic issue, not database. I tried sample code running on different weblogic against same database and it was running smooth. Then I compared shell environment and the correct weblogic had LANG set to UTF-8. When I added following line to setDomainEnv.sh and restarted weblogic, it started to work correctly. Thank you for your assistence.

```
export LANG=en_US.utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

If it might be a problem in the database. oracle databases doesn't support by default accented characters. you have to go to your database run this "  select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS ;"

if you have NLS_LANGUAGE setted to AMERICAN you can not have special characters (é,è,ê etc..) in your tables

To resolve this problem

In windows : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_O10R2\NLS_LANG=FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8MSWIN1252

In Linux : set NLS_LANG=FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8PC850

Comment: The accented characters in his original data would also be covered by WE8ISO8859P1; and are actually missing from his current set EE8ISO8859P2.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your original string vs. stored string, the pattern is that all characters > 0x7f are stored as 0x3f (63). This is typical of a conversion to US-ASCII (or some other character set that has no code points for bytes 0x80-0xff).

It is most certainly a character encoding issue somewhere. The characters you specified that didn't encode are not in ISO-8859-2, which is the character set you have NLS configured for.

You could try ISO-8859-1 (WE8ISO8859P1), e.g. FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8ISO8859P1 (or CZECH_CZECH REPUBLIC.WE8ISO8859P1 if you want to keep the language as Czech). WE8MSWIN1252 is a more complete set than 8859-1.

You could do CZECH_CZECH REPUBLIC.UTF8 too if your database supports it.

Comment: I agree with you. But I do not know, where it happens and how to avoid it. Other applications are implemented and deployed same way and they work correctly. This is a mystery for me.

Comment: Your comments rule out an issue in your application logic as well as a collation issue. It must be either a connection setting, or EclipseLink (I've never used it) is doing some kind of conversion. What is your database connection string/settings (*do not post your host, username, or password*)?

Comment: where? in database SID? in shell environment for database / weblogic?

Comment: Depends on your platform. They're all described at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html

Comment: I ran the code on another machine (linux) and it was OK. I must investigate on monday the difference between this local machine and customer machine. One is evident: HP-UX. I pray that it will be weblogic shell environment, because I cannot touch database.

Comment: If you insert data from the "broken" machine and select it from the working machine, does the string look OK? What about if you insert from the working machine and select from the "broken" on? Have you tried the suggestions from user2688837's answer?

Comment: I cannot, both machines are separated by firewall. The customer machine was down on friday.

Comment: By the way, if you start to get into trouble mucking around with database configuration and such, http://dba.stackexchange.com/ is a good resource (SO specifically for DBA).